# Unwanted Dependency on .NET Framework

Tags: .net, c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, installshield

I have moved my Microsoft Visual Studio 6.0/C++/MFC application to Visual Studio 2008 SP1 using the new MFC Feature Pack classes.  I explicitly use nothing from the .NET Framework.  However, we have trouble installing on a system which does not have .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 installed on it already.  Installshield fails to load an application dll that it needs to call routines in.  Is there an implicit dependency to the .NET Framework built in to every such (C++/MFC) application built using VS2008?  And if not, how do I find out what in the application is causing a .NET dependency?  I would like to eliminate this dependency if at all possible.

Thanks,
Barry

Comment: So is it your application that fails, or is it InstallShield failing during the installation?

Comment: It is when the install attempts to load a dll that i have built.  We build all our dlls using nmake, not visual studio, and do not use the /clr switch.

Comment: Can you include the error message in your post?  Will make it more searchable.

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure the dependency on the framework itself, and not the VC++ 9.0 runtime? Also, are you sure that the build settings don't include the /clr switch?

Here are the VC++ redistributables: http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?FamilyID=9b2da534-3e03-4391-8a4d-074b9f2bc1bf&displaylang=en

Answer (score 4):

The dependency is most probably on the CRT90 (VC runtime). You should compile your custom actions dll statically linking to the runtime instead of the default dynamic linking. You don't have to build the whole application statically linked, InstallShield can install the CRT for you; it's just the custom actions dll that fails, as it executes before IS could run the CRT merge module.

Comment: interesting.  i think you might be onto something here.  i will try this out and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2735477) from Microsoft. In sort, when you install .NET framework 4.5, your previously .NET independent projects will now depend on .NET framework.

Solution:

1. unload the project from the IDE, and then open the project file (.vcproj) in xml or text mode.
2. under the xml root tag (namely "Project"), add the following document fragment:

   <PropertyGroup>
   <AddAdditionalExplicitAssemblyReferences>false</AddAdditionalExplicitAssemblyReferences>
    </PropertyGroup>
3. reload your project.
4. in addition to the previous steps described in the Microsoft's article, check your setup project's "prerequisite" and untick the .NET framework
5. remove the related "launch condition".
6. rebuild msi, now the dependency should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

> Installshield fails to load an application dll that it needs to call routines in.

This sounds like you're having an issue in your installer.

Is this DLL your DLL?  If so, you must have included something in it that is either using the `/clr` compile switch (which adds a .NET depdendency), or are referencing a library (yours or third party) that adds the .NET depedency.

There is nothing in VC++ 2008 that will **require** .NET.  You can build an MFC application that requires nothing but the VC runtimes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the issue here, but I've seen a similar problem with deployment projects. Are you using the MSI Deployment Project (`.vdproj`) provided by Visual Studio? In that case...

If you *add* .NET dependency to a `.vdproj` project and then *remove* it, the dependency will still be there. This is a bug in the GUI! The dependency seems to be gone, but it's still there!

What you need to do is to open the `.vdproj` file in a text editor and remove the .NET dependency manually.